# What are the main tournaments in the chess world?

Tags: rating, tournament

What are the big events that big players visit? Do every big Tournament has an effect on the players rating?

Comment: Are you asking for a comprehensive list, the most emblematic or prestigious ones, a particular chess tour having multiple venues during the year...? Please explain a bit more your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to know about tournaments for top players, I would direct you to [2700 chess (scroll down under the list of players)](http://2700chess.com).

If you consider a " big tournament" an open tournament with let's say 100 participants (and maybe 1 or 2 of them are top players), then do a search in some comprehensive chess calendar, e.g.: [chess-calendar.eu](http://chess-calendar.eu) or [FIDE's calendar](https://www.fide.com/calendar/tournaments.html).

---

Not just the biggest tournaments affect player's FIDE rating, almost every small tournament can do that, too (all FIDE needs is some... money).

Therefore the only exceptions I can think of are friendly matches and alternative chess tournaments (Fischer's chess, Basque chess etc.).